# Show a Div after rolling over another div- How To?

Tags: css, hover

I have a div where I want to show another div once I roll over it. Here is my code:

```
#DivButton:hover {
width:100%;
}

#DivButton:hover #Div_To_Show {
display: block;
}

#Div_To_Show {
display: none;
}
```

However, when I try this, it doesn't work. Im trying to show #Div_To_Show once I rollover #DivButton.  Can anyone tell me what exactly it is i'am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you please add the html markup? so we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the CSS3 sibling selector (`~`):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MZQtx/)**

```
<style type="text/css">
#DivButton:hover {
    width:100%;
}
#DivButton:hover ~ #Div_To_Show {
    display: block;
}
#Div_To_Show {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div>
    <button id="DivButton">DivButton</button>
    <div id="Div_To_Show">
        You can see me now!
    </div>
</div>
```

---

This one doesn't depend on CSS3, but requires specific element order:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MZQtx/1/)**

```
<style type="text/css">
#DivButton:hover {
    width:100%;
}
#DivButton:hover #Div_To_Show {
    display: block;
}
#Div_To_Show {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div id="DivButton">
    Default text.
    <div id="Div_To_Show">Extra text!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently supported by IE7+, FF3+, Chrome, etc.

Comment: Must my two div's be wrapped inside a container div? Must the div I want to show come directly after the hover button? Because the way my html is set up, its not like that.  I have the hover buttons in a totally different spot than where my div to show is, many code lines apart.

Comment: @WillingLearner: Any CSS solution requires that the div you want to show/hide comes AFTER the button you hover over. It sounds like you'll need a javascript or jQuery fix.